# React load HTML as response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have some react Code

```
  onFinish = value => {
    fetch(`filter?layout=false&q[city_id_eq]=${this.state.value}`, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(content => document.getElementById('filter-content').innerHTML = content)    
  };
```

It works, BUT the problem is this line:

```
.then(content => document.getElementById('filter-content').innerHTML = content)
```

no scripts can be inserted with .innerHTML or there are ways around, which seem to be super complicated, like here
[Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

I am new to React and I am looking for a way to load HTML including the script I have (which is a map, having around 50 lines of code. More complicated, it's map written in a ruby file... ) Please help, none of the suggested options in the link above helped so far. I kind of need to look for script-Tags in my #filter-content and load them into the Page content.

Comment: The solutions aren't entirely trivial, but they're not hard to implement either - just copy-paste mmm's code into yours, then call it on the `#filter-content`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. Maybe to you it seems easy, but as I am a beginner I cannot debug the code I have very efficiently. For hours I am getting an error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I was hoping there would be someone who can help me as a beginner, but now there is no chance ...